# MySQL: Remove null from rows converted into column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have made a query, where, I am fetching the results of developer's associated project status into column. But, I am struggling to remove the null values.

The following is my query:

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
    CONCAT(
        'CASE when project=''', project, 
        '''and resource_name=''', resource_name,
        ''' then Tracker end AS `', 'Tracker' , '`')
    ) INTO @sql2        
FROM
    finance_dashboard.resource_utilization_data;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT distinct resource_name, ', @sql2, ' FROM         
    finance_dashboard.resource_utilization_data');

                       
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The output comes like this:

```
'babu.balakrishnan', 'Feature', NULL,      NULL
'prasenjit.ghosh',   NULL,      'Feature', NULL
'shamim.akhtar',     NULL,      NULL,      'Feature'
'babu.balakrishnan', 'Support', NULL,      NULL
'shamim.akhtar',     NULL,      NULL,      'Support'
```

What I would like to have in output is something like this:

```
'babu.balakrishnan', 'Feature', 
                   , 'Support'

'prasenjit.ghosh',  'Feature'

'shamim.akhtar',    'Feature'
                    'Support'
```

Is there any possibility of this, by using query only.

**UPDATE1** The group_concat with aggregate gives the result as:

```
 'babu.balakrishnan', 'Feature,Support', NULL, NULL
 'prasenjit.ghosh', NULL, 'Feature', NULL
 'shamim.akhtar', NULL, NULL, 'Feature,Support'
```

**UPDATE2** The table structure is as follows:

`project`, `Tracker`, `resource_name`, `Total_Hours`, `date`,     `project_counts`

The following query inserts data into the table:

```
    insert into finance_dashboard.resource_utilization_data
    select p.project,
    p.Tracker,
    p.resource_name,
    p.estimated_hours as Developer_Estimated_Hours,
    p.date,
    p.project_counts
    from project_stats.resource_utilization_summary p 
    where p.date>=@start_date 
    and p.date<=@end_date
    order by p.date;
```

Certain values can be hardcoded to get the result in required format.

Comment: Yes, that's my question, but, I have been trying to resolve at my end.

Comment: What is your table structure. I'm sure we can work out an easier query

Comment: I will try the below posted solution, if it does not work out, I will post everything here. Thanks.